# Why the Implicit declaration of function 'usleep' is invalid in C99` happened when compile C library in Xcode 6?

Tags: android, c, static-libraries

I try to create C library in Xcode 6 , but it compile error at the code `usleep(2*1000*1000);`.

And the error log is

`/Users/apk/Desktop/test/test.c:37:9: Implicit declaration of function 'usleep' is invalid in C99`

and the another is `/Users/apk/Desktop/test/test.c:37:9: Declaration of 'usleep' must be imported from module 'Darwin.POSIX.unistd' before it is required`

The part of code in `test.c` is like the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int test(const char* dest) {

    ...

  usleep(2*1000*1000);


}
```

And the code in `test.h` is like the following:

```
#ifndef __TEST_H__
#define __TEST_H__

int test(const char* dest);

#endif
```

**Is the error happened due to can not find the header file `<netinet/in.h>`?**

or am I missing something ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your compiler is not able to find the [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) of `usleep()`. You need to add the header file containg the declaration of `usleep()`. Please add `#include <unistd.h>`

Also, you can check the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) for `usleep()`.